# Consolidating dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Could you please help me, I have two date columns:

```
Name  Member_type  start_date  end_date
----  -----------  ----------  ----------
a     1            03-01-2007  25-12-2008
a     2            01-01-2010  07-07-2010
a     1            15-08-2010  31-12-2013
```

For person `a`, I want to return his first start date. 
If he was gone for more than one year since his end date, then I want to return the start date following this end date.
If it's less than 1 year, I want to return his previous start date.

In the above example, his start date should be 01-01-2010.

He first started in 2007, but he left in 2008 and came back in 2010, which is more than a year. So here, his start date would be the date he started after the 1 year gap, which is 01-01-2010.

He again left in 07-07-2010 but came back 15-08-2010, which is less than a year. So, the start date will still be 01-01-2010.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: What "flavor" of SQL are you using (Sql Server, MySql, Oracle, etc.)?  What have you already tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Does `memeber_type` play any role in this query?

Comment: i am using sql 2008..

Comment: no member type is not important

Comment: I'm confused by your terminology. You have *last start date* and *recent start date*.  Does *recent* means the one prior to *last*?  Could you please clarify it in your post?

Comment: i have updated my post. please let me know if it is still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the most recent record, where there is no start date one year before that records start date.  This record contains the start you want.

Here is a way to do it by finding those records, and then getting the most recent date:

```
select t.name, max(t.startdate) as mostRecentRealStart
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.enddate between t.startdate - 365 and t.startdate - 1
                 )
group by t.name
```